# How to prevent other threads to change a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, reference, thread-safety

I created a class that contains the configuration of an application, so that multiple threads can access the values in it. Obviously, I perform locking within the properties and the methods that set or read these values.

```
public class Settings
{
    private readonly object m_BackupServersLocker = new object();
    private readonly List<Uri> m_BackupServers = new List<Uri>();

    private readonly object m_ExcludedFileExtensionsLocker = new object();
    private readonly List<string> m_ExcludedFileExtensions = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The working threads use this property to get the addresses of the remote backup servers.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Uri> RemoteBackupServers
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_RemoteBackupServersLocker)
            {
                List<Uri> endpoints = new List<Uri>();
                foreach (var uri in m_RemoteBackupServers)
                {
                    string uriString = string.Copy(uri.ToString());
                    endpoints.Add(new Uri(uriString));
                }
                return endpoints;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked by the thread which reads the configuration from file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    public bool InsertRemoteBackupServer(Uri uri)
    {
        lock (m_RemoteBackupServersLocker)
        {
            if (uri == null) return false;
            return m_RemoteBackupServers.Add(uri);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked by the thread which reads the configuration from file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool RemoveRemoteBackupServer(Uri uri)
    {
        lock (m_RemoteBackupServersLocker)
        {
            if (uri == null) return false;
            return m_RemoteBackupServers.Remove(uri);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The working threads use the property to get the list of excluded extensions.
    /// The property is also invoked by the thread which reads the configuration from file, in order to update the exclusion list.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> ExcludedFileExtensions
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_ExcludedFileExtensionsLocker)
            {
                List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                foreach (var extension in m_ExcludedFileExtensions)
                {
                    string extString = string.Copy(extension);
                    temp.Add(extString);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (m_ExcludedFileExtensionsLocker)
            {
                m_ExcludedFileExtensions.Clear();
                foreach (var extension in value)
                {
                    temp.Add(extension);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to return the `IEnumerable<Uri>` and the `IEnumerable<string>`, I performed the copy of the `string`s using the `string.Copy` method. But is it really necessary to make that copy? I decided to make a copy of `string`s according to the following reasoning: if the properties simply return the member attribute (ie a reference to that attribute), the reader threads could change them, so I decided to return a deep copy of these lists.

However, the strings are immutable, so is it unnecessary to make a copy of these lists by copying each string and each uri from them? In other words, if I change the `ExcludedFileExtensions` property in the above sample as follows, then could a reader thread change the original `string`s within the `m_ExcludedFileExtensions` variable?

```
public IEnumerable<string> ExcludedFileExtensions
{
    get
    {
        lock (m_ExcludedFileExtensionsLocker)
        {
            return new List<string>(m_ExcludedFileExtensions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` type.

Here's the MSDN Article for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

Essentially,

```cs
return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(m_ExcludedFileExtensions);
```

will provide a wrapper around your list without doing a deep copy, but prevent anyone from externally modifying the underlying list.  And, of course, strings themselves are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the `ExcludedFileExtensions` method, is doing some things you may not have to do.

You only need to return a copy of the list contents on a `get`, if

1. There is a chance that the **contents** of the list changes by operations within your `Settings` class (i.e. you `Add` or `Remove` items), or
2. You want to prevent clients from casting it to a `List<string>` and then using it to `Add` or `Remove` elements.

Otherwise you can simply do:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ExcludedFileExtensions
{
    get
    {
        var current = m_ExcludedFileExtensions;
        return current;
        // If it could change/you want to prevent client casts:
        // return an immutable copy.
        // return current.ToArray();
    }
    set
    {
        // Personally I find a setter replacing the entire contents
        // rather odd, but then again I don't know your use case.
        var newList = value != null ? value.ToList() : new List<string>();
        m_ExcludedFileExtensions = newList; 
    }
}
```

You will also have to change the declaration of `m_ExcludedFileExtensions` to:

```
private volatile List<string> m_ExcludedFileExtensions = new List<string>();
```

And yes, strings are immutable, so you will never have to clone them when returning them.